# Return message on deleted message

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So i want to add a message when someone writes in this channel

Code

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    formats = ['jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'svg']
    attachments = [f for f in message.attachments if f.filename.split('.')[-1] in formats]
    if message.channel.name == 'bild' and not attachments:
        await message.delete()
    
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Do I only add ctx to the on_message(message) and finish it of with ctx.send?

Comment: What do you mean by "i want to add a message when someone writes in this channel"? Do you want to send a message to that channel?

Comment: Yes, send a message to that channel that say, you are not allowed to send just text, something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

````
async def on_message(message):
   formats = ['jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'svg']
   attachments = [f for f in message.attachments if f.filename.split('.')[-1] in formats]
   if message.author == bot.user:
       return
   if message.channel.name == 'dps-test' and not attachments: 
       await message.delete()
       await message.channel.send('Här kan du endast lägga upp bild på ditt DPS-Test, text med bilden funkar.')
       
   await bot.process_commands(message)```
````

Answer (score 1):

You can use `channel.send` to send a message to a specific channel.

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    formats = ['jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'svg']
    attachments = [f for f in message.attachments if f.filename.split('.')[-1] in formats]
    if message.channel.name == 'bild' and not attachments:
        await message.delete()
        await message.channel.send('You cannot send message without an image.')
    
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: Ahh had the in the wrong order, but now it post a message, butdeletes it and loop it endless